# Check if a simple, undirected graph is triconnected

Tags: algorithm, graph, correctness

## Problem

Given a simple, **undirected** graph G = (V, E), where |V| = n = number of nodes and |E| = m = number of edges, check whether G is triconnected. That is, whether G remains connected (a path exists from each node to all the other nodes) after randomly removing any two edges.
Required time complexity: O(n^2(n + m))

## My solution

For each node in G do the following:

1. Check whether the node has at least 3 edges to 3 different nodes: O(1).
2. Ignore the node and run depth-first search on the remaining graph to check whether it is still connected: O(n + m)

Time complexity: O(n(n + m)) = O(n^2(n + m)).

Is my solution correct?

Comment: If you can have multiple edges between the same nodes, then no.

Comment: It’s a simple graph. I edited the question accordingly.

Comment: The answer is no. Take `a, b, c, d, e, f` Now `[a, b], [b, c], [c, d], [d, e], [e, f], [f, a], [a, c], [d, f]`. You will say it's triconnected, but it's not (remove `[c, d]` and `[f, a]`). The general case is two clicks connected by two additional edges from and to different nodes.

Comment: You are asking if the graph is 3-edge-connected. 3-connected usually means that any 2 *nodes* can be removed without disconnecting the graph.

Comment: @Yonlif Oh wait, my algorithm will still work. I considered the case of two kite-looking graphs connected by a single edge. Removing that edge will disconnect the graph. However, my algorithm will detect that when it runs DFS to check for connectivity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, consider the graph with vertices `X` and `*`.

```
  *   *
 /|\ /|\
*-+-X-+-*
 \|/ \|/
  *   *
```

This graph is 3-edge-connected but if you delete `X`, it's disconnected.

Answer (score 0):

You usually check connectivity with max flow. You set capactity 1 to every edge, pick two nodes and compute maxflow between them. The result is the number of completely different paths between the two nodes (different as in no shared edges). 
To make sure the entire graph is 3 connected means you need to pick every pair of nodes and compute max flow between them.

Max flow with Ford–Fulkerson algorithm has a complexity of O(m * max(f)) where max(f) is the max flow. However, since the algorithm looks to increase flow at every step we can stop as soon as flow == 3 (we don't care if there are even more paths). So this makes the complexity O(m).

Since you do this for every pair of nodes you get a complexity of O(n^2 * m). Since V <= E (especially after you do your quick edge count check) O(n+m) = O(m) so it's the same complexity as what's required.